# How to fetch the string of an array instead of it's value

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have a list of array to hold my country code where the value is used to fetch the corresponding flag icon. However I will also be using the country code as a prepend for my mail where it will look something like

(CA) +1 123456789

but I'm only able to fetch the value which is stored as CA making the number look more like

CA 123456789

My array is being stored like this in `settings.php`

```
"country_codes" => [
        "AF" => "(AF) +93",
        "AX" => "(AX) +358",
        "AL" => "(AL) +355",
        "DZ" => "(DZ) +213",
        "AS" => "(AS) +1-684",
        "AD" => "(AD) +376",
        "AO" => "(AO) +244",
        "AI" => "(AI) +1-264",
        "AG" => "(AG) +1-268",
        "AR" => "(AR) +54",
        "AM" => "(AM) +374",
```

And I'm calling it in my `mail.blade.php`

```
Name: {{$input['name']}}
Contact Number: {{$input['country_code']}} {{$input['contact']}}
```

How do I change the way I call the value so it fetches me (AF) +93 instead of AF

Comment: in which folder is your `settings.php` file?

Answer (score 0):

If `settings.php` is in the config folder, then,

With facade

```
Contact Number: {{Config:get("settings.country_codes.".$input['country_code']."") }} 
{{$input['contact']}}
```

OR
with helper

```
Contact Number: {{config("settings.country_codes.".$input['country_code']."") }}  
{{$input['contact']}}
```

Comment: does my answer helped with your concern?